# Show a snackbar to a menu click event in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a menu on android and want to show a simple snackbar anywhere after there was a click on a menu item. Whatever I put something else instead of "???" doesn't work. The whole app is from the Android studio default tab view template. This is the code I have:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Snackbar.make("????", "Pressed Setting", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
    if (id == R.id.help_settings) {
        Snackbar.make("???", "Pressed Help", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Why is it behaving like that? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using a CoordinatorLayout ?

Comment: You need to pass `view` there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change

```
Snackbar.make("???", ....)
```

to

```
Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView(), .....);
```

You must pass in a `View` to the `Snackbar`'s **static** `make` method.

## EDIT:

On some devices the snackbar can appear below the system's controls menu, and for that reason you may wanna call `findViewById(android.R.id.content)` to display the snackbar correctly:

```
Snackbar.make(getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content), .....);
```

Comment: Doesn't work like it's supposed to. It puts the SnackBar behind the control buttons on the bottom of the screen and if the button is not pressed immediately it looses focus and cannot be pressed.

Comment: Yes that does happen on some devices like Google's Nexus, in order to show the snack bar above the controls' menu you need to add a call to `findViewById(android.R.id.content)`. That is the identifier of the screen's main content view, which is guaranteed to be above the controls menu.

Comment: Why not just `findViewById(android.R.id.content)`? his call is from `onOptionsItemSelected` which is in a activity

Answer (score 4):

This is how you show `Snackbar` on menu item click:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Snackbar.make(this.findViewById(R.id.action_settings), "Pressed Setting", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if (id == R.id.help_settings) {
        Snackbar.make(this.findViewById(R.id.help_settings), "Pressed Help", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I get error message when pressing the menu item. The answer below works fine.

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me thx, I was missing the .show()

```
Snackbar.make(getCurrentFocus(),"settings clicked",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 3):

tried this, it worked fine

```
Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), 
        "Pressed Settings", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, it worked with me

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Snackbar.make(getCurrentFocus(), "U Clicked Settings",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
            return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### For Androidx Fragment and Kotlin

`getCurrentFocus()`, `findViewById()` and `getWindow()` won't work directly.

To use those functions, first get the instance of Activity and then cast it to your activity (The one that contains the current fragment). For example:

```
Snackbar.make((activity as YourActivity).findViewById(R.id.action_settings), 
    "Pressed Settings", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```